# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with quotes

Tags: java, linux, exec, runtime.exec

I am trying to run ffmpeg via the exec call on linux. However I have to use quotes in the command (ffmpeg requires it). I've been looking through the java doc for processbuilder and exec and questions on stackoverflow but I can't seem to find a solution.

I need to run

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://127.0.0.1/vod/sample start=1500 stop=24000" -re -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/qltv
```

I need to insert quotes into the below argument string. Note simply adding single or double quotes preceded by a backslash doesn't work due to the nature of how processbuilder parses and runs the commands.

```
String argument = "ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/vod/"
                    + nextVideo.getFilename()
                    + " start=" + nextVideo.getStart()
                    + " stop=" + nextVideo.getStop()
                    + " -re -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/qltv";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Make an array!

exec can take an array of strings, which are used as an array of command & arguments (as opposed to an array of commands)

Something like this ...

```
String[] arguments = new String[] { "ffmpeg", 
"-i", 
"rtmp://127.0.0.1/vod/sample start=1500 stop=24000",
"-re",
...
};
```

Comment: you can remove the characters "new String[]"; the braces will automatically produce a string array for you.

Comment: This won't work as 

rtmp://127.0.0.1/vod/sample start=xxx stop=xxx

has to have quotes around it. Putting the argument in a string array doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't it help if you put escaped quotes, as follows: "\"rtmp://127.0.0.1/vod/sample start=1500 stop=24000\""

Comment: I'm on a Windows box right now, but I'll get it working tomorrow and let you know ..

Comment: In the meantime, you could always simplify the call by wrapping the call in a shell script (which expects args $1, $2, $3)

Comment: Thank you amir75. Doing it via the shell script as you suggested works. This doesn't solve the problem with exec and quotes but I'm happy. If you find a solution post back as I know others have had the same problem and might not be able to use shell scripts for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to escape quotes inside your argument string. This is simple enough to do with a preceding backslash.

E.g.

```
String containsQuote = "\"";
```

This will evaluate to a string containing just the quote character.

Or in your particular case:

```
String argument = "ffmpeg -i \"rtmp://127.0.0.1/vod/"
          + nextVideo.getFilename()
          + " start=" + nextVideo.getStart()
          + " stop=" + nextVideo.getStop() + "\""
          + " -re -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/qltv";
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet none of the suggestions worked for you because as you had specified, "rtmp://127.0.0.1/vod/sample start=1500 stop=24000" has to have quotes around it and passing a parameter argument to exec with quotes such as "\"rtmp://127.0.0.1/vod/sample start=1500 stop=24000\"" won't do the trick because exec will ignore them, even if inside a String[] array. I don't think there is a straightforward solution unfortunately. What I had done in my own code was try to pass arguments that exec can handle and on the receiving end the program side transform them so that they can be processed adequately.